# What Visual Studio 2008 productivity features are missing from C++ Express edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express to learn a native API for a new project.  What I'm wondering is: what productivity features present in the full version that you take for granted are missing from Visual Studio Express? I'm not referring to large "paid" features like MFC support - I'm thinking of small features (sometimes provided by Add Ins) like ["Copy File to Output Dir"](http://jelle.druyts.net/2005/10/20/CopyToOutputDirectory.aspx)

Also, it doesn't have to be specific to C++ edition - that's just the exact release I happen to be using.

Note: I'm an experienced Java programmer and I most frequently use IntelliJ IDEA (disclaimer: that's just for reference - I'm not looking to compare VS vs. IDEA).

EDIT: Revised to include Add Ins that enhance the experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to develop a C/C++ *WIN32 GUI* application then the major component that is missing is the *resource editor* (i.e. the GUI builder tool).

The express version will still compile resource files, but you will have to create the resource files by hand or use a third party resource editor.

Comment: picked for crucial point - you can't edit Win 32 GUI apps with express edition!

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use addins are sorely missed, for example Visual Assist, which is **the** productivity booster.

Answer (score 1):

I was all like "oh, let me google that for you", but Microsoft made life difficult indeed. Seems that Wikipedia is our best source at this moment:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express